# Convert file content to nested list

Tags: python

I have a text file that consist

2, 1, 3

3, 1, 3

2, 9

My output should be

[[2,1,3],[3,1,3],[2,9]]

How do I do it?

I've tried

```
data=[]
for line in open(file,'r'):
    items = line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')
    items = [item.strip() for item in items]
    (data.append(items))
return data
```

But [['2,1,3'],['3,1,3'],['2,9']] came out. I don't want the output to hace the quotation.

Comment: I have tried data = []
    for line in open(file,'r'):
        items = line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')
        items = [item.strip() for item in items]
        (data.append(items))
    return data 
But it seems to have the output [['2,1,3'],['3,1,3'],['2,9']]. I don't want the quotation in the list.

Comment: Add what you tried to the question as properly formatted code, not as comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `split(',')` because `strip()` only remove the leading and trailing whitespaces.

After splitting you can convert to string to integer using `map(int, line.strip().split(','))`. This will call `int()` function on every element in the list.

```
res = [list(map(int, line.strip().split(','))) for line in open('test.txt')]
```

**Output:**

```
[[2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 3], [2, 9]]
```

Comment: Sorry but can you explain it too?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use list comprehension:

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [[int(n) for n in line.strip().split(',')] for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()]
```

Basically, `readlines()` returns a list where every element is a line.

`['2, 1, 3\n', '\n', '3, 1, 3\n', '\n', '2, 9']` .

We want to split each line (if it contains numbers to a list of its own

The line

```py
[line.strip().split(',') for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()]
```

would give the following output:

`[['2', ' 1', ' 3'], ['3', ' 1', ' 3'], ['2', ' 9']]`

Since I assume the wanted output is a list of integers, we need to convert each element to int, this can also be achieved by adding using a list comprehension:

```py
[[int(n) for n in line.strip().split(',')] for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()]
```

(`line.strip()` will check if a line is empty or not)

**Output**:

`[[2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 3], [2, 9]]`

Comment: Thank you!! Can you explain it?

Comment: @PythonUser428 Sure, added some explanations for clarity :)